# How to use a SCSS color variable in a Material UI and Gatsby site?

Tags: sass, material-ui, gatsby

Trying to figure out how to use a color variable from a SCSS file I keep getting an error:

> ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
>
> Generating development JavaScript bundle failed
>
> Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an
> options object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - options has an unknown property 'data'. These properties are valid:    object { implementation?, sassOptions?, additionalData?, sourceMap?,
>   webpackImporter? }
>
> File: src/styles/main.scss

I've followed the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sass/?=gatsby-plugin-sass) and I've installed `gatsby-plugin-sass` and added it to *gatsby-config.js*:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    data: `@import "${__dirname}/src/styles/main.scss";`,
  },
},
```

I've added the following to *gatsby-browser.js*:

```js
// SCSS
import './src/styles/main.scss'
```

I've tried to bring it in my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

// Material UI
import { AppBar, Toolbar, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

// Components
import Logo from './logo'
import Navigation from './navigation'

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  toolbar: {
    background: $FooBar,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  navigation: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
}))

const Header = ({ title, menu }) => {
  const { toolbar, navigation } = useStyles()

  return (
    <>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar className={toolbar}>
          <Logo name={title} />
          <Navigation className={navigation} menu={menu} />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </>
  )
}

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```

and I tried to import it directly into the component with:

```
import '../styles/main.scss'
```

### Research

[Include sass in gatsby globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833884/include-sass-in-gatsby-globally):

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        data: `@use "${__dirname}/src/styles/main.scss";`,
      },
    },
```

```
import style from '../styles/main.scss'
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  toolbar: {
    background: style.FooBar,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  navigation: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
}))
```

- [Import sass variables to gatsby component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145521/import-sass-variables-to-gatsby-component)
- [Gatsby Build Breaks SCSS Export Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66012444/gatsby-build-breaks-scss-export-variables)
- [How to include SCSS Glob in a Gatsby project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349282/how-to-include-scss-glob-in-a-gatsby-project)
- [Gatsby fails after using Sass files with '@use 'sass:color'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920833/gatsby-fails-after-using-sass-files-with-use-sasscolor)

```
import style from '../styles/main.scss'
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  toolbar: {
    background: style.FooBar,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  navigation: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
}))
```

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    implementation: require('sass'),
  },
},
```

I do not get a build error in the terminal but the background color passed to the component doesn't show up.

In a Gatsby site with Material UI how do I bring in a SCSS color variable to use within a component?

Broken down basic variation of what I've tried to do:

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    data: `@import "${__dirname}/src/styles/main.scss";`,
  },
},
```

To this:

```
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
      sassOptions: {
         data: `@import "${__dirname}/src/styles/main.scss";`,
      },
    },
```

It seems that [`node-sass` has some deprecated dependencies](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27754), so alternatively to this workaround, you can try upgrading your plugin package to the [`3.0.0` version](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27754#issuecomment-764786636).

Comment: added Sandbox with suggested changes and no effect.